# Why do I keep getting error 1005: Can't create table (errno: 150)?

Tags: mysql

I created the following tables in the mentioned order. But I get an error when I create the `enrolls` table.

I know it has to do with the foreign key constraint. But I feel I have done everything right. I don't know what I'm doing wrong:

```
create table Course (
    CourseNo integer(10),
    CourseName varchar(50),
    Department varchar(20),
    primary key (CourseNo)) Engine = InnoDB;

create table Section (
    CourseNo integer(10),
    SectionNo integer(10),
    Instructor varchar(50),
    primary key (CourseNo, SectionNo),
    foreign key (CourseNo) references Course(CourseNo)) Engine = InnoDB;

create table Student (
    SSN varchar(9),
    FirstName char(50),
    LastName char(50),
    Street char(50),
    City char(50),
    State char(50),
    Zip char(5),
    primary key (SSN)) Engine = InnoDB;

create table Enrolls (
    SSN varchar(9),
    SectionNo integer(10),
    CourseNo integer(10),
    foreign key (SectionNo) references Section(SectionNo),
    foreign key (CourseNo) references Section(CourseNo),
    foreign key (SSN) references Student(SSN),
    primary key (SSN, SectionNo, CourseNo)) Engine = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you have done wrong while defining foreign key. The below one's in exact

```
foreign key (SectionNo) references Section(SectionNo)
foreign key (CourseNo) references Section(CourseNo),
```

In your `Section` table you have two columns defined as primary key `primary key (CourseNo, SectionNo)`. So in your FK you must reference both of them with two fields/column like

```
foreign key (CourseNo, SectionNo) references Section(CourseNo, SectionNo)
```

Which thing means, your last table must be created this way:

```
create table Enrolls (
    SSN varchar(9),
    SectionNo integer(10),
    CourseNo integer(10),
    primary key (SSN, SectionNo, CourseNo),
    foreign key (CourseNo, SectionNo) references Section(CourseNo, SectionNo)
    ) Engine = InnoDB;
```

See a demo fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/741b2

Comment: Thank you so much! Makes a lot of sense!